# From absolute path to relative path

Tags: url, uri

I've seen this code in the net and I dont understand how from

`"../../../path"` you get `"/relative/sub/foo/sub/file"` where is the sub/foo/sub ....

```
var uri = new URI("../../../path");
// make path absolute
var relUri = uri.absoluteTo("/relative/sub/foo/sub/file"); // returns a new URI instance
// relUri == "/relative/path"
```

Comment: Which lang do you program in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think like this (folder system):

- relative

  - sub

    - foo

      - sub2

        - file.js
- path.txt

Its like a you are in cmd, with a current directory all the time.

1. "relative/sub/foo/sub2/file.js" points to file.js. Alright?
2. Then you want to come to path.txt (from the sub2 folder).
3. ../ means "go up a folder"
4. ../../../ means go three folders up from sub => relative
5. and then get path.txt

Hope you understand. I'll post more info soon.